# Display parent name by Its ID in its child Iteration in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

How can we display parent name by id while showing the child data, child data is having *parent id*  and parent name should be displayed instead of ID.

Parent Class

```
export class Parent {
  'id': number;
  'name': string;
}
```

Child Class

```
export class Child {
  'id': number;
  'name': string;
  'parentId:number;
}
```

Child HTML code sample

```
<div>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">ID</th>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Parent Id</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody *ngFor="let cl of childList">
        <tr>
          <td>{{cl.id}}</td>
          <td>{{cl.name}}</td>
          <td>{{cl.parentId}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

and the resulted out put is

```
ID .  Name    .  Parent Id
1  .  Shireen .  11
2  .  Talisa  .  11
3  .  Olenna  .  9
4  .  Myranda .  8
```

**Now I wanted to display the parent name instead of ID**

for example like below

```
ID .  Name    .  Parent Name
1  .  Shireen .  Raj
2  .  Talisa  .  Raj
3  .  Olenna  .  Nag
4  .  Myranda .  John
```

Thanks in advance and happy to share the code if wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the getter for parent, pass the id and get the name:

```js
  childList:Child[] = [
    {id: 1, name: 'child1', parentId: 10},
    {id: 2, name: 'child2', parentId: 11},
    {id: 3, name: 'child3', parentId: 12},
  ]

  parentList: Parent[] = [
    {id: 10, name: 'Parent10'},
    {id: 11, name: 'Parent11'}
  ]

  getParentNameById(id: number) {
    const parent =  this.parentList.find((parent) => parent.id === id)
    if (!parent) {
      // we not found the parent
      return ''
    }

    return parent.name
  }
```

Html template now call this new function:

```js
<tbody *ngFor="let cl of childList">
    <tr>
        <td>{{cl.id}}</td>
        <td>{{cl.name}}</td>
        <td>{{getParentNameById(cl.parentId)}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

All working code you can see here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dsjsch

**EDIT**

@gaurangdhorda suggested use pipe instead of calling method inside of html template.

Here the code of pipe that can be used in html template for getting name of parent by id:

```js
@Pipe({ name: 'name_by_id' })
export class GetNameByIdPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(parentList: Parent[], id: number) {
    const parent =  parentList.find((parent) => parent.id === id)
    if (!parent) {
      // we not found the parent
      return ''
    }

    return parent.name
  }
}
```

After adding this pipe to `declarations` in `AppModule` (or another depends of project structure). Html template can be edit to using pipe `name_by_id`:

```html
<tr>
    <td>{{cl.id}}</td>
    <td>{{cl.name}}</td>
    <td>{{parentList | name_by_id:cl.parentId }}
</tr>
```

`parentList | name_by_id:cl.parentId`

- `parentList` - it will be the first argument in function `transform` in pipe class, we pass our array of `Parent`
- `cl.parentId` - it will be the second argument, we pass the id of parent

I've updated the code in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dsjsch

Comment: It's good practice to use Custom pipe () in {{ }} rather directly calling any method in {{ }}

Comment: The logic given by @ivan is working good, am grateful for that. As 'Gaurang Dhorda 'suggested can we use pipe(), how to use pipe() instead of calling a method.

Answer (score 0):

Change the child class as to

```
export class Child {
  'id': number;
  'name': string;
  'parentId:Parent;
}
```

For ID of parent use this way

```
<div>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">ID</th>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Parent Id</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody *ngFor="let cl of childList">
        <tr>
          <td>{{cl.id}}</td>
          <td>{{cl.name}}</td>
          <td>{{cl.parentId.id}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

For name of the parent use this way

```
<div>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">ID</th>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Parent Id</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody *ngFor="let cl of childList">
        <tr>
          <td>{{cl.id}}</td>
          <td>{{cl.name}}</td>
          <td>{{cl.parentId.name}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

But you have to pass the parent data and in the child list for it